# how can i make it so that i can't unselect my choise?

Tags: javascript, html

**How can i make it so that i can't unselect my choise? if i click again on the same text i don't want the popup to disappear.**

I whant to be able to select any of the options, but just one at a time and if i select it i whant all of them to be unavailable until i refresh the page, then i cand select another one but just one, i dont know if it makes sense, im very bad at explaining things :)
I know it's kind of useless but I really need this for a project of mine, can anyone please help me with this?

```js
let clickedId = null
function clickTest(id) {
  if(clickedId){
    if(id!=clickedId){
      return null
    }else{
      clickedId = null
    }
  }else{
    clickedId = id
  }
  var senior = document.getElementById(id);
  senior.classList.toggle("show"); 
}
```

```css
.junior  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .adult {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .senior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.junior .juniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .adult .adulttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .senior .seniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.junior .juniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.adult .adulttext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.senior .seniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.junior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .adult .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .senior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>  
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="junior" onclick="clickTest('myjunior')">JUNIOR
  <span class="juniortext" id="myjunior" >A Simple junior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="adult" onclick="clickTest('myadult')" >ADULT
  <span class="adulttext" id="myadult" >A Simple adult Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="senior" style="text-align: left;">
  <div class="senior" onclick="clickTest('mysenior')" >SENIOR
  <span class="seniortext" id="mysenior" >A Simple senior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question,we can check if the previous clickedId are the same with current id,if they are the same then we do not do anything,otherwise,we  need to hide the previous element and show the current clicked element

```
let clickedId = null
function clickTest(id) {
  if(id == clickedId){
    return
   }
  if(clickedId){
    document.getElementById(clickedId).classList.toggle("show")
   }
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show")
  clickedId = id
}
```

Full code

```js
let clickedId = null
function clickTest(id) {
  if(id == clickedId){
    return
   }
  if(clickedId){
    document.getElementById(clickedId).classList.toggle("show")
   }
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show")
  clickedId = id
}
```

```css
.junior  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .adult {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .senior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.junior .juniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .adult .adulttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .senior .seniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.junior .juniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.adult .adulttext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.senior .seniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.junior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .adult .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .senior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>  
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="junior" onclick="clickTest('myjunior')">JUNIOR
  <span class="juniortext" id="myjunior" >A Simple junior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="adult" onclick="clickTest('myadult')" >ADULT
  <span class="adulttext" id="myadult" >A Simple adult Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="senior" style="text-align: left;">
  <div class="senior" onclick="clickTest('mysenior')" >SENIOR
  <span class="seniortext" id="mysenior" >A Simple senior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

Update:
Based on your comment(just want to one item to popup,I provide another solution)

```
let clickedId = 'myadult'
let clicked = false
function clickTest(id) {
  if(clicked || id!=clickedId){
    return
  }
  clicked = true
  document.getElementById(clickedId).classList.toggle("show")
}
```

Test code

```js
let clickedId = 'myadult'
let clicked = false
function clickTest(id) {
  if(clicked || id!=clickedId){
    return
  }
  clicked = true
  document.getElementById(clickedId).classList.toggle("show")
}
```

```css
.junior  {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .adult {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
   .senior {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.junior .juniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .adult .adulttext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
  .senior .seniortext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.junior .juniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.adult .adulttext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.senior .seniortext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.junior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .adult .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
 .senior .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>  
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="junior" onclick="clickTest('myjunior')">JUNIOR
  <span class="juniortext" id="myjunior" >A Simple junior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="adult" onclick="clickTest('myadult')" >ADULT
  <span class="adulttext" id="myadult" >A Simple adult Popup!</span>
</div>
  </td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"> 
<div class="senior" style="text-align: left;">
  <div class="senior" onclick="clickTest('mysenior')" >SENIOR
  <span class="seniortext" id="mysenior" >A Simple senior Popup!</span>
</div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: great! but now i can select any other option and i wanted to be able to select just one of them :(

Comment: @GGalusca have you tested my code,now your can only pop up one item

Comment: yes, but after i select one item and the pop up shows up i whant to make the other items unavalable

Comment: @GGalusca so you just want to only popup one item?then how can you switch to other item?

Comment: i don't want to switch to another item, i want to be able to chose just one of them because just one of these 3 items will be the correct answer and i dont whant to be able to change my answer if i got it wrong

Comment: @GGalusca updated my answer,check again